# Compile Error Using MutableClassToInstanceMap with Generics

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am getting the following compile error "The method putInstance(Class, T) in the type MutableClassToInstanceMap is not applicable for the arguments (Class, Number)" on the putInstance method call. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?? Thanks!

```
public class TestMutableClassToInstanceMap {

    public final MutableClassToInstanceMap<Number> identifiers = MutableClassToInstanceMap.create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
        numbers.add(new Integer(5));
        TestMutableClassToInstanceMap test = new TestMutableClassToInstanceMap(numbers);
    }

    public TestMutableClassToInstanceMap(Collection<Number> numbers){
        for (Number number : numbers) {
            this.identifiers.putInstance(number.getClass(), number); //error here
        }
        this.identifiers.putInstance(Double.class, 5.0); // This works
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the `putInstance` method, as opposed to the regular `put`, is to provide *compile-time* type safety. In this case, you and I can easily reason that `number` must be of the type given by `number.getClass()`, but to the compiler, that information is "lost." That is, as far as *it* knows, maybe `number` is an Integer and `number.getClass()` is Long.class; it's not "smart" enough to figure out this is safe.

Solution: just use `put()`!  You still get the runtime checks, and you can still use the typesafe `getInstance()` method after that, such as in `Long l = this.identifiers.getInstance(Long.class);`.

(Final tip: watch out, because `Long.class` and `long.class` can both exist in a `ClassToInstanceMap` and be mapped to different values!)

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's answer is great. Besides, you can tell from the method definition that the compiler is not going to allow the call:

- `putInstance` requires (in your case) a `Class<Number>`.
- `number.getClass()` provides a `Class<? extends Number>`

Which is not a direct subclass. Some variance and covariance talk could be useful here.